# How to get an input element that has an array name which I have assigned the value of the index?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

*Please help me, I am just a beginner

I have input fields above this foreach block, but this is the focus of my concern.

```
foreach ($display_eqp as $value){
  $eqpid = $value['Eqp_ID'];
  $available = $value['OnHand'];

  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='center'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' 
            name='request-equipment[". $eqpid ."]' id='". $eqpid ."-checkbox' 
            value=" . $eqpid . " onchange='enableQtyTxtbox(this.value)' disabled></td>";
  echo "<td class='center'><input type='text' class='form-control' 
            style='width: 60px;' name='available-" . $eqpid . "' id='available-" . $eqpid . "' 
            value=" . $available . " readonly></td>";
  echo "<td class='center'><input type='text' placeholder='...' class='form-control'
            style='width: 60px;' onchange='checkQty(this.value, ". $eqpid .")' 
            name='request-quantity[". $eqpid ."]' id='". $eqpid ."' disabled='true'/></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
```

I have 2 javascripts.

1st is this one, where in when an individual checkbox checked state is change, it enabled/disabled and clears the corresponding textbox and enables/disables the submit button also. This is working, that is for individual only and this is triggered by ticking the checkbox.

```
  function enableQtyTxtbox(val) {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(val + "-checkbox");
    var textbox = document.getElementById(val);
    var submitbtn = $("input[type='submit']");
    textbox.disabled = !(checkbox.checked);

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        submitbtn.attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else{
        textbox.value = "";
    }
}
```

now my concern is this 2nd script.

```
function checkValue(id){
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");

    // this does not work: var textbox= $("input[name='request-quantity[]']"); ????


    if (value == "") {
        checkboxes.attr("disabled", true); //this works
        checkboxes.checked = false; // this does not work, please if you could answer this one 
                                    // for me also, it would be a big help.

        // clear textbox
        // disable textbox
    }
    else{
        checkGroup();
    }
 }
```

What I want to do here is to get all the textbox named request-quantity (which is an array with assigned index) and clear and disable it just like the first script. But I dont know how to access the element.

Comment: `checkboxes.attr('checked', false);` to uncheck checkboxes --- I don't understand the other question ?

Comment: If you want to use it as an array, simply use `name='request-quantity[]'` and then use jQuery's selector to select input fields what that particular name:
`$('input[name="request-quantity[]"]')`

Comment: @sodawillow I tried that also, but it doesn't work in the checkValue function.

Comment: @sodawillow I know now why it doesn't work, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('input[name^="request-quantity"]')` is the selector to get the items that have a name starting with 'request-quantity'.

[Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[Other attribute Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Thanks this help. I can now call the textboxes. can I also change the value of all the textboxes using this selector?

Comment: Yes you can set the value with this selector.